# GCC running in CMD but not in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code

I started a small programming course, and we are trying to set up the gcc compiler in Visual Studio Code in my students' laptops. I had a problem with two students in which we installed MinGW, we edited the Path variable and added the address at which MinGW\bin is stored. We ran gcc in the CMD and it recognized the command. However, when we try to execute a C code in VSC, it keeps saying that gcc isn't recognized as a command, path, etc.  What could be wrong? We already have the extensions "C, C++" and "Code Runner".

Comment: try opening VSC through cmd, then again try the gcc command

Answer (score 1):

> we edited the Path variable

This edit is applied to new command windows, etc but not to anything already open and running.

Shut down VSCode and restart.